# How to ignore labels when autocompleting using datalist and option tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, I have a datalist tag related to an input, and I have a set of options in this datalist, with each option having values and labels. The problem is: I want the autocomplete to ignore labels values. For example, if I search "city" it returns "phoenix" and "austin", but I dont want to return anything at all.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input list='mylist'>
<datalist id='mylist'>
  <option value ="phoenix" label="city">
  <option value ="austin" label="city">
  <option value ="arizona" label="state">
  <option value ="texas" label="state">
</datalist>

</body>
</html>
```

How can the autocomplete only search based on values?

Comment: I didn't know HTML had an autocomplete. Probably it's not worth using

Comment: we can write a javascript function to omit search of label in datalist option but then it will be equivalent to creating a autocomplete input box from scratch.